# C - Switch not Breaking

Tags: c, switch-statement, break

I am working on a state machine via a switch. However, it seems to go through `MACRO_READ_TEXT`, `MACRO_READ_FIRSTCHAR`, `MACRO_READ_NAME`, `MACRO_READ_ARG`, and `MACRO_ARG_RECEIVED` all in one-go, rather than one iteration of the switch at a time (as it's supposed to).

So for starters here's the switch itself.

```
switch(curMacState)
            {
                case MACRO_READ_TEXT: // Just a regular character
                    printf("macroreadtext \n");
                    if( curChar == '\\' )
                    {
                        macroStartIndex = curIndex;
                        macroStartIndexFound = true;
                        curMacState = MACRO_READ_FIRSTCHAR;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        curMacState = MACRO_READ_TEXT;
                        break;
                    }
                    break;

                case MACRO_READ_FIRSTCHAR:
                    printf("macroreadfirstchar \n");
                    if( isalpha(curChar) || isdigit(curChar) )
                    {
                        // Since realloc just allocates PAST the null character, we will need to
                        // simply write over the null character, and then add our own later.
                        // Location of the null character:
                        int macroNameNullIndex = strlen( macroName );

                        char* newMacroName = realloc(macroName, sizeof(macroName) + sizeof(char)); // Realloc 1 extra char.
                        macroName = newMacroName;

                        macroName[macroNameNullIndex] = curChar;
                        macroName[macroNameNullIndex + 1] = '\0';

                        curMacState = MACRO_READ_NAME;
                        //break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        curMacState = MACRO_READ_TEXT;
                        //break;
                    }
                    break;

                case MACRO_READ_NAME:
                    printf("macroreadname \n");
                    if( isalpha(curChar) || isdigit(curChar) )
                    {
                        int macroNameNullIndex = strlen( macroName );

                        char* newMacroName = realloc(macroName, sizeof(macroName) + sizeof(char)); // Realloc 1 extra char.
                        macroName = newMacroName;

                        macroName[macroNameNullIndex] = curChar;
                        macroName[macroNameNullIndex + 1] = '\0';
                        curMacState = MACRO_READ_NAME;
                        //break;
                    }
                    else if( curChar == '{' )
                    {
                        curMacState = MACRO_READ_ARG_FIRSTCHAR;
                        //break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //break;
                    }
                    break;

                case MACRO_READ_ARG_FIRSTCHAR:
                    printf("MACRO_READ_ARG_FIRSTCHAR \n");
                    if( curChar == '}' )
                    {
                        // dont mark end of macro yet.
                        curMacState = MACRO_READ_ARG_RECEIVED;
                        //break;
                    }
                    else // read in cur char to an arg
                    {
                        macroArgTable[argIndex] = malloc( sizeof(char) * 2 ); // [_]['\0']
                        char* curArg = macroArgTable[argIndex];
                        curArg[0] = curChar;
                        curMacState = MACRO_READ_ARG_NAME;
                        //break;
                    }
                    break;

                case MACRO_READ_ARG_NAME:
                    printf("MACRO_READ_ARG_NAME \n");
                    if( curChar == '}' )
                    {
                        curMacState = MACRO_READ_ARG_RECEIVED;
                        //break;
                    }
                    else // read in cur char to an arg
                    {

                        char* curArg = macroArgTable[argIndex];
                        int argNullIndex = strlen( curArg );

                        char* newCurArg = realloc(curArg, sizeof(curArg) + sizeof(char)); // Realloc 1 extra char.
                        curArg = newCurArg;

                        curArg[argNullIndex] = curChar;
                        curArg[argNullIndex + 1] = '\0';
                        curMacState = MACRO_READ_ARG_NAME;
                        //break;
                    }
                    break;

                case MACRO_READ_ARG_RECEIVED:
                    printf("MACRO_READ_ARG_RECEIVED \n");

                    argIndex++;

                    if( curChar == '{' )
                    {
                        curMacState = MACRO_READ_ARG_FIRSTCHAR;
                        //break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Mark end of macro (technically the last char, the closing bracket.)
                        macroEndIndex = curIndex - 1;
                        macroEndIndexFound = true;
                        //char* newStrFileContents = processMacro( strFileContents, macroName, macroArgTable );
                        //strFileContents = newStrFileContents;
                        // this should return a str

                        curMacState = MACRO_READ_TEXT;
                        macroStartIndexFound = false;
                        macroEndIndexFound = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    break;

                default: // Just a regular character
                    break;
            }
```

Everything is working fine until the first time "\" is read and MACRO_READ_FIRSTCHAR gets called. When I run this through gdb, I see all the states just get printed out at once at this breakpoint.
(Example of gdb output before and after this problem)

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffd578) at proj1.c:215
215                                                     printf("macroreadtext \n");
(gdb) c
Continuing.
macroreadtext

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffd578) at proj1.c:215
215                                                     printf("macroreadtext \n");
(gdb) c
Continuing.
macroreadtext

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffd578) at proj1.c:215
215                                                     printf("macroreadtext \n");
(gdb) c
Continuing.
macroreadtext
macroreadfirstchar
macroreadname
macroreadname
macroreadname
MACRO_READ_ARG_FIRSTCHAR
MACRO_READ_ARG_NAME
MACRO_READ_ARG_NAME
MACRO_READ_ARG_NAME
MACRO_READ_ARG_NAME
MACRO_READ_ARG_NAME
MACRO_READ_ARG_NAME
MACRO_READ_ARG_NAME
MACRO_READ_ARG_NAME
MACRO_READ_ARG_RECEIVED
MACRO_READ_ARG_FIRSTCHAR
MACRO_READ_ARG_NAME
MACRO_READ_ARG_NAME
MACRO_READ_ARG_NAME
MACRO_READ_ARG_NAME
MACRO_READ_ARG_RECEIVED

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffd578) at proj1.c:215
215                                                     printf("macroreadtext \n");
(gdb) c
Continuing.
macroreadtext

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffd578) at proj1.c:215
215 

                                                printf("macroreadtext \n");
```

Comment: Hm, your breakpoint seems to be at `printf("macroreadtext\n")`; the program will run continuously until this line is hit. The `break`s probably work as expected; you might try to make a breakpoint _before_ the switch statement to verify that.

Comment: How exactly did you set the breakpoint?

Comment: I don't see the `printf` outputs as evidence that the switch isn't breaking. In fact, you have some superfluous breaks. What's the code look like outside of the switch where it is actually looping?

Comment: `char* newMacroName = realloc(macroName, sizeof(macroName) + sizeof(char)); // Realloc 1 extra char.`  You take the `sizeof ( pointer)` here.  I think you want strlen() (or remember the allocated length and use that)

Comment: @Ctx unfortunately it's not just that, the program literally jumps from curIndex5 to curIndex26 after all the things are printed (I have this being displayed) and I tried moving the breakpoint.

Comment: @lurker it's just a while( curChar != '\0' )

Comment: @joop thanks for that tip

Comment: Update: I tried putting the breakpoint a little higher and the behavior seems more normal now. Let me see if I can get it running from here.

Comment: If compiling optimized, this may be expected behavior.

Comment: `macroArgTable[argIndex] = malloc( sizeof(char) * 2 ); // [_]['\0']`  - If this is supposed to be a string, either use `calloc()` or be sure to NUL terminate this in your logic.

Comment: Stylistic note: you have too many variables, which you all need to maintain. Most of them have an implicit value, based on the state. Also: you are repeatedly calling strlen() and realloc(). Just remember the current symbol length and use a (fixed size) for the names, and only malloc() a string once you know the final size.